# When using DotNetCore 2.0 Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 package not resotred

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package-restore

NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

**Toold VS 2017 Operating System is Windows 10**

Comment: See here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18452

Comment: Thanks for Quick Response  Installing latest package for Microsoft Composition 1.0.31 resolved the warning for me, your link does help to explain it further though so many thanks